# html on tumblr div height not behaving

Tags: html, css

I've got some html with css, this in fact:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{Title}</title>
  </head>
  <style>
  html {
      background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/9sVraBS.jpg');
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
  }
  header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/5RVc2sw.png');
  }
  h1 {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', "Arial", sans-serif;
  }
  #title {
      margin: auto;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
  }
  #navigation {
      display: inline-block;
  }
  </style>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div id='navigation'>
        <a href='/art'>Art</a><br><br>
        <a href='/music'>Music</a>
      </div>
      <div id='title'>
        <h1>{Title}</h1>
        {block:Description}
            {MetaDescription}
        {block:Description}
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

which looks like this when I test it in browser:
[image]

which is as I intended, but when I copy and paste the exact same code in tumblr's 'edit html', I get this:
[image]

The header div is not following the specified 'height:100%' and being cut short after the content is finished.

I don't understand what's happening since my version works fine but the exact same does not work on tumblr. Is there a special something I need to specify to make the div height 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default margin of `body` coming from browser's stylesheet.

Add to your CSS

```
body { margin: 0}
```

Ref: [Default Browser Styles](http://www.dev-hq.net/html-css/21--default-browser-styles)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{Title}</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    body{ margin:0px}
  html {
      background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/9sVraBS.jpg');
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
  }
  header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/5RVc2sw.png');
  }
  h1 {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', "Arial", sans-serif;
  }
  #title {
      margin: auto;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
  }
  #navigation {
      display: inline-block;
  }
  </style>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div id='navigation'>
        <a href='/art'>Art</a><br><br>
        <a href='/music'>Music</a>
      </div>
      <div id='title'>
        <h1>{Title}</h1>
        {block:Description}
            {MetaDescription}
        {block:Description}
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```